# My game looks weird and had a error when I bring it up

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a picture of what it looks like but it says its to big, it says java sprit error and my game looks like I turned on a super secret setting from 1.8 the staticky one. [image]

Comment: “I have a picture of what it looks like.” Please send the picture, even if you have to reduce the resolution. It helps a ton.

Comment: How do I do that??

Comment: I like to reduceimages.com

Comment: Ok I added that

Comment: plz help me!!!!

Comment: Can you tell the exact error?

Comment: it says it is a java script error and a bunch of other numbers and letters after that.

Comment: I just deleted the game and redownloaded it and now it doesn't do it anymore!! ty for trying to help though!

Comment: This current screenshot is so low-quality it's impossible to know what you're talking about.

Comment: Seems like the Anaglyph option. It was removed a couple versions back, but if you're playing an old version of MC, that would be it. It's meant to be used with 3D glasses (colored). Switch it off and it will go back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

As SF. said this is the anaglyph setting. It gives the red and blue effect for 3d glasses (like at one point at move theaters). Disable it and it will be fixed.